# Linq to nhibernate string comparison

Tags: nhibernate

I have a question on linq to nhibernate. I need to create a query in which I could use string comparison:

```
session.Linq<User>()
       .Where(u => String.Compare(u.Name, givenName) < 0)
       .ToList()
```

Do I understand correctly that this is not supported in linq-to-nhibernate? Is there a way to use string comparison in linq-to-nhibernate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new integrated provider in NHibernate 3 allows extending it to support pretty much any construct you want.

Check http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2010/07/nhibernate-linq-provider-extension.html for a full example.

Of course, you'll need to think of a reasonable HQL representation of that expression.

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer needed. The lambda expression in the question is now supported.